# flutter ios - page change to grey when in release mode

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I experienced that on my screen some components turned gray when I changed them to release mode in xcode, but when using debug mode in the emulator it was still safe
[image: like this]

but when I use release mode it becomes gray like below
[image: like this]

I have an issue with the following code:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/token.dart';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_exchange_rate_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_gold_silver_price_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/_model_list_app_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/api_service.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_slide_announce_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_url_app_category_app.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_url_banner_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/api/model_url_safety_api.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/login.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/main.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/notifications.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/util/constant.dart';
import 'package:launcher_apps/widget/app_category.dart';
import 'package:marquee/marquee.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:showcaseview/showcaseview.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';

import 'api/app_list.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  var accessToken;
  String? propHasSeenShowcase;
  Home({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.accessToken,
    required this.propHasSeenShowcase
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    if (_seen) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
            .dismiss(),
      );
    } else {
      await prefs.setBool('seen', true);
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
            .startShowCase([_first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth, _six]),
      );
    }
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey _first = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _second = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _third = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _fourth = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _fifth = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _six = GlobalKey();
  static final Config config = Config(
    tenant: 'xxx',
    clientId: 'xxxx',
    scope: 'xxxxx',
    clientSecret: "xxxx",
    redirectUri: kIsWeb
        ? 'http://localhost:8483'
        : 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf',
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );

  final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);

  ModelGoldSilverPriceApi listGoldSilverPrice =
      ModelGoldSilverPriceApi(gold: [], silver: []);

  ModelExchangeRate listExchangeRate =
      ModelExchangeRate(data: [], tanggalBerlaku: '');

  ModelUrlAppCategoryApi listUrlAppCategory = ModelUrlAppCategoryApi(data: []);

  ModelUrlBannerApi listUrlBanner = ModelUrlBannerApi(data: []);

  ModelUrlSafetyApi listUrlSafety = ModelUrlSafetyApi(data: []);

  bool isLoading = false;
  // AppListHardcode appList = AppListHardcode();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
      
    checkFirstSeen();
    _getDataGSPrice();
    _getDataEx();
    _getBanner();
    _getDataCat();
    _getDataSafety();
  }

  void _getDataGSPrice() async {
    listGoldSilverPrice = (await ApiServiceListApp().getGoldSilverPrice());
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _getDataEx() async {
    listExchangeRate = (await ApiServiceListApp().getModelExchangeRate());
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _getBanner() async {
    listUrlBanner = (await ApiServiceListApp().getListDataBanner());
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _getDataSafety() async {
    listUrlSafety = (await ApiServiceListApp().getListDataSafety());
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _getDataCat() async {
    listUrlAppCategory = (await ApiServiceListApp().getListDataCategory());
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Carousel
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  String formatNumber(int number) {
    return NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(number);
  }

  String formatDateToFull(String dateStr) {
    DateTime date = DateTime.tryParse(dateStr) ?? DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy').format(date);
    return formattedDate;
  }

  // void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) => checkFirstSeen();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime yesterday = now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    List<CarouselItemData> carouselItems = [
      CarouselItemData(
          header:
              "Manhours LTI Free - ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].periode : 'Loading'} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime(0, listUrlBanner.data[0].month)) : ''} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].year : ''}",
          footer: "",
          value:
              "PTAR : ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(listUrlBanner.data[0].ptar) : 'Loading'}"),
      CarouselItemData(
          header:
              "Manhours LTI Free - ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].periode : 'Loading'} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime(0, listUrlBanner.data[0].month)) : ''} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].year : ''}",
          footer: "",
          value:
              "Contractors : ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(listUrlBanner.data[0].contractors) : 'Loading'}"),
      CarouselItemData(
          header:
              "Manhours LTI Free - ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].periode : 'Loading'} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime(0, listUrlBanner.data[0].month)) : ''} ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? listUrlBanner.data[0].year : ''}",
          footer: "",
          value:
              "Martabe Site : ${listUrlBanner.data.isNotEmpty ? NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(listUrlBanner.data[0].martabeSite) : 'Loading'}"),
      CarouselItemData(
          header: "Martabe Safe Days",
          footer:
              "Last LTI : ${listUrlSafety.data.isNotEmpty ? DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(listUrlSafety.data[0].lastLti)) : 'Loading'}",
          value:
              "${listUrlSafety.data.isNotEmpty ? NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(listUrlSafety.data[0].countDays) : 'Loading'} Days"),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        backgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_BLUE,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/images/logo-atas.jpg'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // InkWell(
          //   onTap: () {
          //     // setState(() {
          //     //   jmlNotif++;
          //     // });
          //     // showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
          //     //   context: context,
          //     //   builder: (context) => ModalNotifications(),
          //     // );
          //     // Navigator.push(context,
          //     //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotificationsUser()));

          //     Navigator.of(context).push(_routeNotifications());
          //   },
          //   child: Badge(
          //     badgeContent: Text("$jmlNotif"),
          //     position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 5, end: -8),
          //     badgeColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_GOLD,
          //     child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          //   ),
          // ),
          Showcase(
            key: _first,
            title: 'Refresh',
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: COLOR_PRIMARY_BLUE),
            tooltipBackgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_GOLD,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            targetShapeBorder: const CircleBorder(),
            description: 'Tap here to refresh page.',
            showArrow: true,
            targetBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(250),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: isLoading
                  ? const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Icon(
                      Icons.refresh,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _getDataGSPrice();
                  _getDataEx();
                  _getBanner();
                  _getDataCat();
                  _getDataSafety();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Showcase(
              key: _second,
              title: 'Sign Out',
              titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: COLOR_PRIMARY_BLUE),
              tooltipBackgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_GOLD,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              targetShapeBorder: const CircleBorder(),
              showArrow: true,
              targetBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(250),
              ),
              description: 'Tap here to sign out.',
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.logout,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text('Are you sure want to sign out?'),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () =>
                                    Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Cancel',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 67, 107),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => logout(),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Yes',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 67, 107),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ))))
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Showcase(
                key: _third,
                title: 'Slider',
                titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    color: COLOR_PRIMARY_BLUE),
                tooltipBackgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_GOLD,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                targetShapeBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                showArrow: true,
                targetBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                description: 'Slide to view another information.',
                child: CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    initialPage: 0,
                    enlargeCenterPage: false,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 8),
                    autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                    autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  ),
                  items: carouselItems.map((text) {
                    return Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 207, 160, 82),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      text.header,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 14.5,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 8),
                                    Text(
                                      text.value,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 67, 107),
                                        fontSize: 21,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    if (text.footer != "")
                                      Text(
                                        text.footer,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )),
          ),

          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Showcase(
                    key: _fourth,
                    title: 'Gold & Silver Price',
                    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: COLOR_PRIMARY_BLUE),
                    tooltipBackgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY_GOLD,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    targetShapeBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                    showArrow: true,
                    targetBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    description:
                        'This is running text about gold & silver price and foreign exchange rates.',
                    child: Marquee(
                      text:
                          "Gold : ${listGoldSilverPrice.gold.isNotEmpty ? '${listGoldSilverPrice.gold[0].price} (${listGoldSilverPrice.gold[0].status})' : 'Loading'} & Silver : ${listGoldSilverPrice.silver.isNotEmpty ? '${listGoldSilverPrice.silver[0].price} (${listGoldSilverPrice.silver[0].status})' : 'Loading'} (refers to goldprice.org) | USD/IDR : Rp. ${listExchangeRate.data.length > 0 ? '${listExchangeRate.data[0].harga} (${listExchangeRate.data[0].status})' : 'Loading'} | AUD/IDR : Rp. ${listExchangeRate.data.length > 0 ? '${listExchangeRate.data[1].harga} (${listExchangeRate.data[1].status})' : 'Loading'} | CAD/IDR : Rp. ${listExchangeRate.data.length > 0 ? '${listExchangeRate.data[2].harga} (${listExchangeRate.data[2].status})' : 'Loading'} | AUD/IDR : Rp. ${listExchangeRate.data.length > 0 ? '${listExchangeRate.data[3].harga} (${listExchangeRate.data[3].status})' : 'Loading'} (refers to Tax Rate with validity ${listExchangeRate.tanggalBerlaku}) ",

                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 67, 107)),
                      // scrollAxis: Axis.horizontal,
                      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      blankSpace: 50.0,
                      velocity: 20.0,
                      // pauseAfterRound: Duration(seconds: 0),
                      startPadding: 10.0,
                      accelerationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      // accelerationCurve: Curves.linear,
                      decelerationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                      // decelerationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
                    ))),
          ),

          // List App
          Expanded(
              flex: 30,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: listUrlAppCategory.data.isEmpty
                      ? Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      : AppCategory(
                          listUrlAppCategory: listUrlAppCategory,
                          numberKey: [_fifth,_six],
                        ))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Route _routeNotifications() {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
          const NotificationsUser(),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
        const end = Offset.zero;
        const curve = Curves.ease;

        var tween =
            Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        return SlideTransition(
          position: animation.drive(tween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // ==================== baris function dialog dan login/logout ====================

  void showError(dynamic ex) {
    showMessage(ex.toString());
  }

  void showMessage(String text) {
    var alert = AlertDialog(content: Text(text), actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
          child: const Text('Ok'),
          onPressed: () {
            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            });
          })
    ]);
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => alert);
  }

  void logout() async {
    await oauth.logout();
    // showMessage('Logged out');

    setState(() {
      // perubahan setelah logout lakukan disini
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginApp()),
      );
    });

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) => const AlertDialog(
        content: Text('You are now logged out'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CarouselItemData {
  final String header;
  final String footer;
  final String value;

  CarouselItemData(
      {required this.header, required this.footer, required this.value});
}
```

I've tried copying debug mode and then changing to release but it still doesn't work

Comment: There should be an error related to ui. In some cases the UI works perfect in debug mode but show grey screen in release mode. Try to run in debug mode and see logs you will see an exception related to UI and if it not works then run your app in release mode and run command: (flutter logs) and then see the logs